# Extract non-digit characters before certain character in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
> row   extract_column
> 0 412952266-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 1 512952766-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 2 212952766-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 3 112953066-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 4 712953066-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 5 612953366-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 6 912953366-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 7 412954866-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 8 312954966-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 9 212954966-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 10    612955866-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 11    912256266-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 12    812256366-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 13    512256566-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 14    412256566-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 15    312256566-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 16    212256566-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 17    612256566-desiredtext1»randtext-irrelevant
> 18    812956666-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 19    912957166-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 20    012957866-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 21    12952966-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 22    2012953066-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 23    012953066-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 24    312953066-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 25    112254166-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
> 26    712254166-desiredtext2»randtext-irrelevant
```

I want to get the desiredtext1, desiredtext2 fields from extract_column. The desired data is always followed by the » symbol and preceded by 9 digits followed by a dash.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `extract`

```
df.extract_column.str.extract(r'-([^\.]*)\»', expand=False)
```

Comment: That returns everything after the 9 digits and dash - a good first step. The desired output, however, is just desiredtext1, desiredtext2, excluding the » and everything after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.extract_column.str.extract('-(\\w+)')
Out[100]: 
               0
0   desiredtext1
1   desiredtext1
2   desiredtext1
3   desiredtext1
4   desiredtext1
5   desiredtext1
6   desiredtext1
7   desiredtext1
8   desiredtext1
9   desiredtext1
10  desiredtext1
11  desiredtext1
12  desiredtext1
13  desiredtext1
14  desiredtext1
15  desiredtext1
16  desiredtext1
17  desiredtext1
18  desiredtext2
19  desiredtext2
20  desiredtext2
21  desiredtext2
22  desiredtext2
23  desiredtext2
24  desiredtext2
25  desiredtext2
26  desiredtext2
```